# How can a wire be influenced by a electromagnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, conductors

I have a problem in one of my project. Here are some details on this project :

A train is moving on tracks. To know its location, some beacons (transmitters) were placed at different locations in between the two tracks. Those beacons are always transmitting. There is a receiver fixed beneath the train. When the train goes above one of those beacons, it receives the data. Just to be clear, the field created by the beacons are only powerful enough so that the train can only receive it at the location of the beacon +/- a few dozens of centimeters. So until this point everything works perfectly.

Inside each beacon, there is solenoid that creates the field.

There is also a cable that follows the tracks and it is placed in the middle of the two tracks. So whenever there is a beacon, the beacon is placed above the cable. But now, the train detects a beacon even when it is a few meters away from it. After a few experiments, we have concluded that the cable transmits the field created by the beacon. To resolve this issue, we put a wire around the beacon to cancel the field in the cable. That works perfectly fine. We also tried putting the loop in between the beacon and the wire but there are no results (no attenuation or increase) (c.f. the diagrams).

[image: Setup]
[image: Experiments]

However there are some physical phenomena that my teammates and I do no understand. In our opinion, the experiment where we put the wire around the beacon works because the loop contains the solenoid's ferrite, where all the field power is located. And that is why we are not seeing anything in the experiment where the loop is not including the solenoid.
However if that is really the explanation of what is happening, how do we explain that the cable transmits the field ? Just to be clear, this cable is open on both ends and it for sure does not circle around the solenoid of each beacon.

Hence the question: what is the physical phenomenon that causes the cable to transmit the field created by the beacon?